# Восстановление случайных чисел

Tags: случайные-числа, генерация-случайных-данных, fortran

Я работаю со случайными на языке Fortran. При вызове программы у меня генерируется множество случайных чисел. Но иногда при анализе полученных результатов, сделанных на основе программы появляется необходимость вернуться к старому результату расчёта, и соответственно вновь сгенерировать те же самые числа (1 в 1), как я могу это сделать?

Comment: Инициализируйте генератор случайных чисел в начале программы `srand(...)` фиксированным числом, либо числом заданным пользователем вместе с другими исходными данными для расчета.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Стандартная, для Фортран 95 и выше, процедура `RANDOM_SEED` с аргументом `get` предназначена ровно для этих целей. Впрочем, она, в любом случае, несколько лучше  GNU расширения `SRAND`, т.к. позволяет аргументом `put` задать все возможные состояния ДСЧ, а не только 2³² избранных.